# Even with delay all objects appear in display at once... what do I do?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local path = pather:getPath(startx,starty, endx,endy)

    if path then
        compPath = display.newGroup();
        for node, count in path:nodes() do
            --timer.performWithDelay( 1000, function (event) 
                print(('Step: %d - x: %d - y: %d'):format(count, node:getX(), node:getY()))
                local tile = display.newRect((node:getX() * 50) - 25, (node:getY() * 50) - 25, 48, 48)
                colorCell(tile, 0, 0, 255)
                tile.alpha = 0

                usleep(500);
                transition.fadeIn( tile, { time=1500 } )
                compPath:insert(tile)
            --end
            --)

        end
   end
```

I have this path that I am trying to animate as it appears but it seems to all show at once even with a delay or if I put it in a timer to go in spurts.  Do I have to be displaying it using framerate at every second instead?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not incrementing the delay time in the loop, so you're scheduling *all* your path nodes to show up in 1 second.

Remember, the loop is going to execute almost instantly (computers are fast).

Try this:

```
if path then
    compPath = display.newGroup();
    local revealInterval = 500
    local revealTimeout = 0
    for node, count in path:nodes() do
        timer.performWithDelay( revealTimeout, function (event)
            local tile = display.newRect((node:getX() * 50) - 25, (node:getY() * 50) - 25, 48, 48)
            colorCell(tile, 0, 0, 255)
            tile.alpha = 0
            transition.fadeIn( tile, { time=1500 } )
            compPath:insert(tile)
        end
        )

        revealTimeout = revealTimeout + revealInterval
    end
```

end